# Adding Controls to a Bing Map Webpart for SP 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, bing-maps

I am using this WebPart to display Bing Maps, I did lots of research to find out, how can I put controls on it as one shown in picture in link but didn;t find any hint except AJAX might help, can anyone just give me hint to what should I search for to get what i want please.

[My Version of Map](http://s10.postimage.org/idlq27d9l/My_Version_of_Map.jpg)

[Desired Map (Controls in Blue background)](http://s14.postimage.org/4hs8lk8ch/Desired_Map_Version.jpg)

[Here is the Code for Webpart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/SP2010BingMapsWebPart.aspx)

I actually found what I want, and its on this link

[Bing AJAX SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)

But I wonder how I can use it in my Webpart as its giving me the source code, but how to use that source for a webpart ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the controls on the map, you can set them in the map options when you initialise the map. JS is fine - have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427603.aspx)